# Nhibernate Reading/Saving Session Pattern, what is the exact transaction behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, ado.net, transactions

All,

This is the pattern used to read/write data using n-hibernate session:

```
using(var session = factory.OpenSession())
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    // all the code that uses the session goes here
    // use session to load and/or save entity
}
```

My question is:

When you start a transaction, it starts a database transaction on the connection but I don't see a corresponding commit statement, rather the using statement on tx will call tx.Dispose(). Looking at n-hibernate source (from AdoTransaction class that uses SqlTransaction object), the underlying transaction object is never commited but disposed as you can see below. **So, are we to assume that SqlTransaction provider will call commit before disposing?** Is that somewhere document for SqlClient provider for ado.net?

```
if (isDisposing)
{
    if (trans != null)
    {
        trans.Dispose();
        trans = null;
        log.Debug("IDbTransaction disposed.");
    }

    if (IsActive && session != null)
    {
        // Assume we are rolled back
        AfterTransactionCompletion(false);
    }
}
```

Clearly, I am missing something since I could not locate the code that flushes the session when tx.Dispose() is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea there is that you are supposed to call `CommitTransaction` yourself as part of the `using` block, as when the garbage collector comes around to `Dispose` the object, there could be the case that the transaction itself threw an error, in that instance you don't want the `Dispose` to commit it, you just want to dispose it.

Comment: That makes, sense but is it really neccessary to use try/catch when calling 'tx.Commit()' inside the using statements? If tx throws exception on commit, the using statment will call tx.Dispose(); which should do a rollback (if inside a transaction) and clean up.

Comment: I would say that you should apply the using-statement to your transactions whenever possibly. Call Commit() on the transaction object usually as the last thing inside the using-statement. That way you will avoid committing if an exception occurs. No need to also use try-catch for this.

Comment: @ActiveX You're probably right about `try catch`, it's safe to say in `Dispose` if the transaction is still active, it should be rolled back :)